# clear before batchUpdate instead of after in google app scripts

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am pretty new to google app scripts.
I have built a script that lets me download big csv's directly from a URL into a google sheet (over 40000 rows). I want to combine this with a function that clears the sheet BEFORE i update the script with the new csv content. However, after many failed attempts, the clearing always happens AFTER the new update, leaving me with an empty CSV.

```
function importcsv(spreadsheet, url, sheetname) {

  var csvContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  var resource = {requests: [{pasteData: {data: csvContent, coordinate: {sheetId: sheet.getSheetId()}, delimiter: ","}}]};
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource, spreadsheet.getId());

}

function clearstuff(sheet, type, columns, startcell) {
  // optional finetuning - if you don't understand this then you don't need to change it
  var insertRange = startcell
  var rows = sheet.getMaxRows(); //set manually if you don't want to clear every row
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(insertRange).offset(0, 0, rows, columns);

  //clearing commands - don't change

  if (type == 'custom range') {
    target.clearContent();
  } else if (type == "Nothing") {
  } else {
    target.getSheet().clear();
  }
} 


function wrapper() {

  // To authorise the script go to Editor/Services/+/Google Sheets API/Add

  // Configurations
  var csvUrl = 'https://https://www.stats.govt.nz/assets/Uploads/Annual-enterprise-survey/Annual-enterprise-survey-2019-financial-year-provisional/Download-data/annual-enterprise-survey-2019-financial-year-provisional-csv.csv'; // insert your url (csv format)
  var sheetname ='Sheet1'; // Name of the sheet to be used(eg "Sheet1")
  var clearBehaviour = 'custom range'; //alternatives: "Nothing", "whole sheet", "custom range"
  var columns = 2; // if clearBehaviour == "custom range"...how many columns would you like to clear
  var insertRange = sheetname + "!A1"; // if clearBehaviour == "custom range"... Selects the top left cell of all the cells to be cleared

  // setup - don't change
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetname);

  clearstuff(sheet, clearBehaviour, columns, insertRange);
  // dowloading and pasting - don't change

  importcsv(spreadsheet, csvUrl, sheetname);
  //var csvContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(csvUrl).getContentText();
  //var resource = {requests: [{pasteData: {data: csvContent, coordinate: {sheetId: sheet.getSheetId()}, delimiter: ","}}]};
  //Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource, spreadsheet.getId());

}
```

I thought building a "wrapper" around two seperate functions would help sort out the order but it doesn't so I'm really not sure anymore how to carry on.

I also tried Utilities.sleep() but that doesn't help either. Every time after the script says that it is completed i can see the new data for a split second before it all disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that in your situation, in order to reflect `clearContent()` and `clear()`, `flush()` is required to be used before Sheets API is used in the function of `importcsv`. So, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
clearstuff(sheet, clearBehaviour, columns, insertRange);
// dowloading and pasting - don't change

importcsv(spreadsheet, csvUrl, sheetname);
```

#### To:

```
clearstuff(sheet, clearBehaviour, columns, insertRange);
// dowloading and pasting - don't change

SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // Added

importcsv(spreadsheet, csvUrl, sheetname);
```

#### Note:

- When I saw your URL, it's `var csvUrl = 'https://https://www.stats.govt.nz...`. In this case, please remove one `https://`. Please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush)

Comment: Amazing. That solved it. Thank you! I spent so much time on this and not only have you helped me solve it but also explained to me why it doesn't work so I've now learned something valuable.
Thanks also for the note. That wasn't my real csv. I just wanted to hide the actual address because it contained sensible information and i was just quickly looking for a stand-in so i accidently copied it wrong....

Thanks again. You're a champ

Comment: @dukesilver Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.